# Реализация поисковой строки со смещающимися по мере ввода выпадающими списками

Tags: reactjs, input, search, dropdown

Как создать нечто подобное поиску с выпадающими списками как на Youtrack на React. Конкретно, не понимаю как заставить смещаться выпадающий список под позицию курсора после ввода очередного поискового ключа. Буду благодарен за любую информацию по этому вопросу. Вот видео демонстрация: https://youtu.be/Q4VbK5rePLI

Comment: Приложите примеры того как оно должно выглядеть, желательно анимация или видео. Не все знают что такое Youtrack, и это не что то очевидное и выдает первым в Гугле.

Comment: Вот видео демонстрация: https://youtu.be/Q4VbK5rePLI

Comment: Всеоченьпросто - создаете инпут с автокомплитом на основе запросов к серверу и выподающим списком. Далее создаете тегбар в котором вместо тегов используете созданные напервом шаге инпуты. Все.

Comment: @OlmerDale Спасибо, это понятно, но как сдвинуть dropdown вправо после ввода очередного тега?

Comment: @OlegMusin а для этого ничего специального делать не нужно, это обычный дропдоун. Если у Вас возникает подобный вопрос, то научитесь сначала делать дропдоуны. К тому же способов реализовать дропдаун тоже несколько. Выбор зависит от конкретной задачи, которые никому кроме Вас не известны. Разбейте этот ui компонент на части и делайте по отдельности.

Comment: @user220409 давайте не будем обсуждать кто что умеет, обычный дропдаун будет выпадать на всю длину инпута, а мне нужно смещающийся как на видео.